Undefined class while using __declspec(dllexport) since Visual Studio 17.2
The following code compiles well for Visual Studio < 17.2:
#include <optional>
#include <map>

class __declspec(dllexport) A {
    using M = std::map<int, A>;
    std::optional<M> map_;
};

But failed for Visual Studio 17.2 and newer with an error:
example.cpp
...utility(330): error C2079: 'std::pair<const int,A>::second' uses undefined class 'A'
...optional(159): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<const int,A>' being compiled
...optional(158): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>::_Construct_from<const _Base&>(_Self) noexcept(<expr>)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=A::M,
            _Base=std::_Optional_construct_base<A::M>,
            _Self=const std::_Optional_construct_base<A::M> &
        ]
Compiler returned: 2

It works fine in any version if I drop __declspec(dllexport) from the code or change std::optional to boost::optional.
Is this compiler bug, or I'm missing something?
Behavior is the same for both C++17 and C++20 mode.

Try explicitly declaring the special member functions and then defining them as defaulted in a source file. It sounds like the compiler is over-eager in instantiating some members.

@SebastianRedl I didn't get the idea. Could you please share an example.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8s36sjKPK It seems that the autogenerated special member functions are eagerly instantiated too early.

This is not a compiler error, but a change in STL with the advent of c++20. Look, the problem is that std::optional requires the type to be is_trivially_destructible https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible
Since version c++20, std::optional became constexpr. Therefore, the destructor is implemented not at runtime, but at compile time. See
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/~optional
Returning to your code example, your class A is not is_trivially_destructible because it contains a map_ of M, which can contain the same class A as an object, not as a reference - thus, it is a complex object.
Why does __declspec(dllexport) affect: before std::optional became constexpr, the destructor for std::optional was already generated by your compiler in your DLL. Now it should be generated at compile time by the compiler that will use your DLL, but it actually cannot generate it, since class A is external to it and is clearly not is_trivially_destructible.
Therefore, the compiler's behavior is justified, although not obvious. To understand the problem in more detail, try to execute the following code:
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class __declspec(dllexport) A {
 public:
    mutable std::optional<A> a_;
};


and you will see the problem with is_trivially_destructible:
error C2139: 'A': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_trivially_destructible'

I do not think that boost::optional can be a solution, since, perhaps, in the next versions of constexpr it will come to it too. The correct change is to simplify the logic of the code and store the class by pointer or reference, in which case the type for std::optional will be trivial.

" Look, the problem is that std::optional requires the type to be is_trivially_destructible" - Uh, no? That would mean you couldn't have a std::optional<std::string>, which I have everywhere. Maybe you meant to say something else?

unfortunately these are not my words, this is C++20... you can use it, but inside a binary module, without export: is_trivially_destructible is not a rule if you are not exporting the type. Or use trivial types inside std::optional for export. Actually I think this was a forced measure, since otherwise it is possible to form code with std::optional where it is really unclear how to call a destructor from another module for a value object

Again, source? The C++ standard only says that if the inner type is trivially destructible, then optional's destructor is also, otherwise the destructor calls the inner type's destructor if the optional contains a value. And that shouldn't even be an issue, because the optional's value type is the map, not a plain A, and a map should allow an incomplete value type, probably. It appears that somehow the implementation of this std::optional is instantiating the copy constructor when it shouldn't, probably due to a weird interaction with the (non-standard) declspec attribute.

look on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/%7Eoptional pls. Especially: ~optional(): constexpr since C++20. This means that destructor for std::optional will be created by compiler which is compiling code with std::optional. Before C++20 destructor is implemented in the module which exports class. After C++ 20 destructor of std::optional will be implemented by compiler which calls module which exports class, that is, in the calling module, but in compile time. at this time the class exported from another module is unknown whether it is trivial or not

The OP isn't even using modules. "Created by the compiler" also makes no sense.

there is probably a misunderstanding of how __declspec(dllexport) affects the declaration of classes in DLL, and accordingly, the generation of their code. Please look at this thread: https://reviews.llvm.org/D22034?id=63793
it is about the vftable, but it touches on the topic of how the constexpr interacts with dllexport
